# UIImageView rotation + center change cause the image to blow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to do a UIImageView change every second.

The change can have one of the two:
- Rotation
- Location change

I am using the following:

This is the initialization code:

```
+(instancetype)newWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    MySateliteView *v = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Satelite" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    v.frame = frame;
    v.lastLocation = [SateliteCoordinate new];

    return v;
}
```

This is the full code for the view:

```
-(void)createSateliteViewFromLocation:(SateliteLocation *)location {
     CGPoint center = [self createPointFromLocation:location];
     MySateliteView *locationView;
     for (MySateliteView *v in _satelites) {
        if (v.tag == location.sateliteNumber.integerValue)  {
           locationView = v;
           break;
        }
     }
     if (!locationView) {
        locationView = [MySateliteView newWithFrame:CGRectMake(center.x - 15, center.y - 15, 30, 30)];
        locationView rotate:location.coordinates.degree];
        locationView.tag = location.sateliteNumber.integerValue;

        [_satelites addObject:locationView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
            [self addSubview:locationView];
        }];
     } else {
         if ([locationView needsNewCenter:location.coordinates]) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            locationView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
            locationView.center = center;
            locationView.superview.clipsToBounds = YES;
         }];
     }
     if ([locationView needsRotate:location.coordinates]) {
         [locationView rotate:location.coordinates.degree];
     }
  }
}
```

For some reason, once the center is changed with a rotation already applied, the image is getting larger!

Anyone have any idea why and what I can do?

Thanx!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `locationView.transform = transform;`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code you provided. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Try running this code in a loop, where you change the center every odd case and change the rotation every even case.

The center change causes my image to grow..
I know rotation by itself can change the frame size, what I can't understand is why the image size is changing with every re-center I do

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're experiencing. Rotation by itself cannot **change** the frame size. The transform makes the value returned by `frame` invalid. My hunch is that there is either autoresizing behavior or layout constraint interplay going on. Without a reproducible example, I can't help.

Comment: I have a xib file with only an imageview on it.
The imageview has the following constraints:

[
0 from top
0 from left
0 from right
0 from bottom
]


The problem is that once I set a new center the image view gets blown for some reason..
I know this is not a lot to work with but I am not sure what else I can supply..

Comment: And you are adding the view from the xib into another view after you've initialized it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame is getting larger because you have constraints in a view and you're messing around with the center manually. You shouldn't mix auto layout and manual layout in this way. I'd recommend either:

1. Remove the constraints and do all your view layout manually by overriding `layoutSubviews` and `drawRect:` as appropriate while continuing to keep the code you already have.
2. Interact with the constraints instead of the frame/center/bounds. You can create an IBOutlet from the constraints in the xib so you can modify their values. You can override the system provided `updateConstraints` method in your view to ensure constraints are provided appropriately.

An example of updating the constraints to move your view might look like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: .7, animations: ^{
    self.constraint1.constant = 23;
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints: @[self.constraint2]];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```